# apps-script contacts api synchronus issue

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-script-api, google-contacts-api

I am trying to add/create/get contactGroup based on each contact info by Google Apps Script.
But I have faced asynchronous error while I am using app-script/contacts API.
I can't get latest contactGroup list(it doesn't include contactGroup just added) although I added new contactGroup

I made Google Apps Script by contacts API that can classify each contact to different contactGroup based on email.

```
function test(){
  var group1 = ContactsApp.createContactGroup('group1');
  var groupList1 = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('group1');
  Logger.log(groupList1); // got contactGroup Object

  var group2 = ContactsApp.createContactGroup('group2');
  var groupList2 = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('group2');
  Logger.log(groupList2); // got contactGroup Object

  var group3 = ContactsApp.createContactGroup('group3');
  var groupList3 = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('group3');
  Logger.log(groupList3); // null

  var group4 = ContactsApp.createContactGroup('group4');
  var groupList4 = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('group4');
  Logger.log(groupList4); // null

  var group4 = ContactsApp.createContactGroup('group4');
  var groupList4 = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('group4');
  Logger.log(groupList4); // null

}
```

so, I had to wait about 5000ms to get object before calling `getContactGroup function`
I think there must be a solution to avoid this.
Please help if there is anyone who has ever faced a similar issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imxDa.png)

Comment: So far there's no information regarding this error when calling Contacts API asynchronously. You will need to call the API again after modifying the `contactGroup`.

Comment: Hi, Jess. Thanks for your comment.
Yes, I know, in fact, that is my issue. I have to call API after got contactGroup.
But it takes so much time to wait until GSuite will return correct value of contactGroup.
I have 5000 contacts, so I have to wait endless